# Why is my AppleScript not working?

Tags: applescript

Making an AppleScript but for some reason it isn't working. Any ideas why not?

```
delay 1
set volume 1
say "Hello " & (do shell script "whoami") using "Whisper"
say "Do you want to play a game?" using "Whisper"
display dialog "Do you want to play a game?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 1
if the button returned of the result is "Yes" then
-- say "Bwahahahaha!"
else
-- display dialog "Big mistake" & (do shell script "whoami")
end if
```

Comment: It would be useful to describe the expected behavior

Comment: Yeah. What do you want to achieve and where is it not working

Comment: Is this related to this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/200172/120171

Comment: @bjbk You may be on to something...

Comment: Ha, no, I just enjoy making pranks on applescript with my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, but I had to set volume 6 to make it audible.

"Big mistake" should be "Big mistake " -- that space matters.

Comment: I still can't get any audio on the action buttons, nothing happens. :(

Comment: **--** comments out a line. So changing **-- say "Bwahahahaha!"** to **say "Bwahahahaha!"** should fix that

Comment: Hey, do you have any ideas on how to make this even creepier?